# How to highlight an HTML content and save it to the database for future loads

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highlight, selectedtext

I'm trying to **highlight the selected text contents** by the user inside the HTML page I loaded using PHP + XSL transformation.
I have seen some solutions related with highlighting current selected text, but I need to **save some information to the database** that makes me able to **highlight the same contents** for future loads of the same page, **taking care of all inner elements** that the text could have inside.

The idea is simple: **simulate when you use a marker inside a book**.

Any ideas? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Isaac

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX.

http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp

IMO, DOM location and the STRING range.

something like,

```
DOM_LOCATION: div[0]>p[2]>span[1]
STRING_RANGE: 2:20
```

this means that the string user highlighted from the 2nd character to the 20th character of the 2nd span of the 3rd paragraph of the 1st div, which is "**monstration of some**" from the example below.

```
<div>
    <p>This has no use.</p>
    <p><em>And so is</em> this one.</p>
    <p><span>This</span> is the <span>demonstration of something wonderful</span>.</p>
</div>
```

All you need to do is reverse the DOM location and use the range.

Comment: Yes, I know I'll use AJAX to save it to the DB, but, I was wondering about which kind of information should be enough to make future loads of that highlight.

Comment: Thank you for being more specific. Do you know if the range values are the same for the main browsers (IE,FF,CH)?
I have writed JS code but I found that there are some different characters (TAB, CR, etc.) inside the DOM for each browser, that makes me impossible to trust these range values.

Comment: Yes, specially for IE. and if your doing your html in a non-standard way. IE tries to add missing elements like tbody... tabs, multiple white spaces and CR's are also ignored. I haven't tried if you've written these characters as html entities, though.

Comment: If your going to map the dom again, you should set "tolerance" rules.

Comment: Hi sheeks06 have you got the solution, now I have the same need and stuck at same place, dont know, how and what information to save into database, that highlights the content again.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This feature might help you.

just add `#:~:text=Highlight%20These`

try accessing this link for demo

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588721#:~:text=Highlight%20a%20text`