# Highlight a text with javascript everytime page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am trying to achieve:

The word **online** should appear green while the word **offline** should appear yellow. Everytime my webpage loaded.

What I have done: I have have searched for this on google all day and even on stackoverflow. All I could find is;

```html
<head>
<style>
  .found {
    color:red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="s">
  <div id="a">
    i am online he is offline.
  </div>
  <script id="jsbin-javascript">
    var s = document.getElementById('s');
    var div = document.getElementById('a'); 

    function changeNode(n, r, f) {
      f=n.childNodes; for(c in f) changeNode(f[c], r);
      if (n.data) {
        f = document.createElement('span');
        f.innerHTML = n.data.replace(r, '<span class=found>$1</span>');
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(f, n);
        n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
      }
    }
    //s.onkeyup
    s.onkeyup = function(){
      var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('found');
      while (spans.length) {
        var p = spans[0].parentNode;
        p.innerHTML = p.textContent || p.innerText;
      }
      if (this.value) changeNode(
        div, new RegExp('('+this.value+')','gi')
      );
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

So whenever, I type something into the input box, the words become highlighted. However, I want this to happen automatically without ant input box and the word online in green and offline in yellow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap them in spans in the HTML?

Comment: You can use the javascript onload event  <body onload="myFunction()">

Comment: In all honesty the solution you currently have is not desirable for what you want to do. As @gcampbell recommends splitting them up as elements would be better and styling them would be best.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript

Comment: Try my new answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```html
 <html>
     <head>
       <style>
         .green {
           color: green;
         }
         .red {
           color: red;
         }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 id="colouredText">This is a green text, and here a red text</h1>
      <script>
        var text = document.getElementById("colouredText");
        var words = text.innerHTML.split(" ");
        for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          if(words[i] == "red") {
            words[i] = "<span class='red'>" + words[i] + "</span>";
          }
          if(words[i] == "green") {
            words[i] = "<span class='green'>" + words[i] + "</span>";
          }
        }
        text.innerHTML = words.join(" ");
      </script>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vanilla javascript which:

1. loops through the elements in the document to find the paragraphs;
2. breaks up the paragraphs into space-separated words;
3. replaces every instance of *online* and *offline* with a styled `span`; and
4. reconstructs the paragraph including the styled `spans`

```js
var body  = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

for (var i = 0; i < body.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (body.childNodes[i].nodeName !== 'P') {continue;}

    var textArray = body.childNodes[i].textContent.split(' ');
    body.childNodes[i].textContent = '';

    for (var j = 0; j < textArray.length; j++) {

        if (textArray[j] === 'online') {
            var online = document.createElement('span');
            var onlineText = document.createTextNode('online');
            online.appendChild(onlineText);
            online.classList.add('online');
            textArray[j] = online;
        }

        else if (textArray[j] === 'offline') {
            var offline = document.createElement('span');
            var offlineText = document.createTextNode('offline');
            offline.appendChild(offlineText);
            offline.classList.add('offline');
            textArray[j] = offline;
        }

        else {
            textArray[j] = document.createTextNode(textArray[j]);
        }

        body.childNodes[i].appendChild(textArray[j]);

        if (j < (textArray.length - 1)) {
            var space = document.createTextNode(' ');
            body.childNodes[i].appendChild(space);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.online {
color: rgb(0,255,0);
}

.offline {
color: rgb(255,255,0);
}
```

```html
<p>upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline</p>

<p>underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline underline overline online offline upline downline inline outline</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a very easy and new way to do this.

just add `#:~:text=Highlight%20These`

try accessing this link

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588721#:~:text=Highlight%20a%20text`

Note: Only for chrome :(

Comment: that's not working in firefox. would be really cool though!

Comment: yeah, sadly. I also found that months after I commented this one.

Comment: It doesn't work in all browser, it works only on page first load, it only highlights the first occurrence, there are no way to change the css styles. good finding though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need Javascript to accomplish something like this.  Well at least in the way that you explained.

Why couldn't you just do this with plain html like so:

```
<div id="a">
    i am <span style="color:green">online</span> he is <span style="color:yellow">offline</span>.
</div>
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pp8ab74/)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Is `<text>` an HTML element?

Comment: @Rounin very true, I was using the razor engine, but `<text>` is a razor snippet for a <text> block. good pick up. ill edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using this after you include Jquery. or Just call the startHighlightProcess method when you like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
startHighlightProcess("online","onlineClass");
startHighlightProcess("offline","offlineClass");
});

function startHighlightProcess(keywordToHighlight,classname)
var searchedKeyword = keywordToHighlight;
var newClassToSet = classname;
        function startHighlighting() {                
                    highlightWord(document.body, searchedKeyword.toLowerCase());
            };



            function highlightWord(root, word) {
var classToSet = newClassToSet;
                textNodesUnder(root).forEach(highlightWords);

                function textNodesUnder(root) {
                    var walk = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false),
                        text = [], node;
                    while (node = walk.nextNode()) text.push(node);
                    return text;
                }

                function highlightWords(n) {
                    for (var i; (i = n.nodeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(word, i)) > -1; n = after) {
                        var after = n.splitText(i + word.length);
                        var highlighted = n.splitText(i);
                        var span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.className = classToSet;
                        span.appendChild(highlighted);
                        after.parentNode.insertBefore(span, after);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery - Targeting all paragraphs that satisfy the filter

```
var textToFind = 'online';

$("p:contains('" + textToFind + "')").each(function (i, element) {
    // extract the element content
    var content = $(element).text();

    // replace the text to find with the new mark up
    content = content.replace(textToFind, '<span class="highlight">' + textToFind + '</span>');

    // put back into the element
    element.html(content);
});
```

Be aware that this will replace the contents of the paragraph with the new content, if there are any handlers associated with elements in the paragraph  they will be lost.

Use carefully.